# Деструктуризация массива объектов в js

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, деструктурирующее-присваивание

Входные данные.

```js
const users = [
    {name:'John',age:26,skills:{js:'good',html:'cool'}},
    {name:'Ivan',age:29,skills:{js:'cool',html:'low'}}
    ]
```

Есть массив объектов - список юзеров с именем, годом рождения и набором скиллов.

Посредством деструктуризации, хочу получить в новый users2 тот-же список юзеров, но чтобы у Ивана навык html был - super

Как это сделать?

пытаюсь так:

```html
let user2 = [...users,users[0].skills:{html:'super'}]
```

- не работает.

И я понимаю что эта конструкция не должна так работать. Может кто наставить на путь истинный?
Я так понимаю, массив можно перебрать через map и изменить то что мне нужно точечно, а потом записать в user2, но хотелось-бы увидеть лаконичное решение через деструктуризацию.

Comment: Мне кажется вы неправильно используете инструменты для достижения своей цели. Так извратить код еще постараться нужно. Забудьте про деструктуризацию до тех пор, пока не встретите ее реальное применение в каком-нибудь проекте.

Comment: Хорошо. Как будет правильней всего с точки зрения правильности передать в массив user2 оригинальный user1, но уже с измененным значением?

Answer (score 3):

Простые объекты "в лоб" можно копировать через `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` — Хорошо бы завернуть это дело в функцию и везде вызывать её, чтобы при необходимости усложнить обработку - пришлось менять только код функции.

```js
const a = [
  {name: 'John', age: 26, skills: {js: 'good', html: 'cool'}},
  {name: 'Ivan', age: 29, skills: {js: 'cool', html: 'low'}},
];

const b = deep_copy(a);
b[1].skills.html = "super";

console.log(b[1]); // html: "super"
console.log(a[1]); // Не изменилось


function deep_copy(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

```css
code { white-space: nowrap !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, у нас есть объект `user`, который содержит `.profile`:

```js
const user = {
  profile: { ... }
}
```

И нам нужно создать переменную, которая будет равна `user.profile` и называться будет соответственно.

Можно просто вытянуть свойство:

```js
const user = {
  id: '2ab',
  profile: {
    name: '1',
    surname: '2'
  }
}

const profile = user.profile;

console.log(profile);
```

А можем воспользоваться деструктуризацией:

```js
const user = {
  id: '2ab',
  profile: {
    name: '1',
    surname: '2'
  }
}

const { profile } = user;

console.log(profile);
```

В вашей ситуации просто не нужна, вот как будет выглядеть запись:

```js
let user2 = [...users, users[0].skills.html = 'super']
```

Comment: Логику того что вы написали - я понимаю. Но вы провели работу над объектом, а мне нужно скопировать массив объекта в новую переменную, предварительно немного скорректировав одно из свойств skills второго пользователя.

Comment: `users[0].skills.html = 'super'` изменит значение объекта в исходном массиве, а вложенные объекты из `users` попадут в `user2` (одни и те же), задача упирается в копирование объектов.

Comment: @ФитцЧивэл есть костыльный вариант с `JSON`.`parse`/`stringify` который позволит скопировать объект целиком.